# replacing unknown value in string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm running a process that dumps a bunch of information to files in a directory.  I run the same process later and do a diff on the directories to see what has changed.  I'm getting a bunch of false changes due to a memory address.

For Example:

1. Run 1 gives

   ```
   0xb7390dd0
   ```
2. Run 2 gives

   ```
   0xb73909c8
   ```

I would like to be able to ignore the fact that the memory addresses are different?  What is the best way to accomplish this?

I can't use `.replace()` as I don't know what the address will be beforehand.

Comment: you can create a regex to match the pattern of value and replace the matched value

Comment: Why not exclude the memory address from the information you dump in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

you can create a regex to match the pattern of value and replace the matched value

```
>>> pattern = r'0x\w{8}'
>>> matcher = re.compile(pattern)
>>> matcher.match('0xb73909c8: has the error')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x01E25288>
>>> matcher.match('0xb73909c8: has the error').group()
'0xb73909c8'
```

then you can do

```
>>> '0xb73909c8: has the error'.replace(matcher.match('0xb73909c8: has the error').group(), 'Address')
'Address: has the error'
```

Comment: And you can write `r'0x\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w'` shorter as `r'0x\w{8}'`.